# break a loop outside of its scope

Tags: c#

if i had

```
   string command = null;
    while(command != "exit")
    {
      Console.Write(">$");
      ProcessCommand(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public static void  ProcessCommand(string Command)
    {
        if(Command == "exit") break;
    }
```

this wont work because the loop is not on the calling function, is there a way to break the loop inside the function that i called from the loop scope?

just look how ugly is this

```
string command = null;
while(command != "exit")
{
  Console.Write(">$");
  command = Console.ReadLine();
  if(command == "exit") break;
  ProcessCommand(command);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the `break` statement inside the `while`, not in the other method. You could write it like this:

```
bool continueLoop;
do
{
  Console.Write(">$");
  continueLoop = ProcessCommand(Console.ReadLine());
} while (!continueLoop);

public static bool ProcessCommand(string command)
{
    return command != "exit";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead return bool from your method

```
public static bool  ProcessCommand(string Command)
{
    if(command == "exit") return false;
}

while(command != "exit")
{
  Console.Write(">$");
  if(!ProcessCommand(Console.ReadLine())) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to break? You are already testing in the while loop? So just assign command = Console.ReadLine() and then when it == "exit" the loop will exit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
string command = null;
while(command != "exit")
{
   Console.Write(">$");
   ProcessCommand(command=Console.ReadLine());
}

public static void  ProcessCommand(string Command)
{
   if(Command == "exit") return;
}
```

Comment: This won't do anything. the `return` statement will just return from the `ProcessCommand` method.

Comment: @Joe and thats what i want, as soon as it returns the loop breaks because command = "exit", i wonder why no one came up with this answer except the noob himself

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `command =` in front of the parameter. In which case, `ProcessCommand` does nothing in its current guise (presumably this is just for demonstration purposes). A more readable format, would be to assign command on the line before, and pass that through as a parameter to `ProcessCommand`, provided that method actually does something.

Comment: @Joe it does alot of things ;) i just included the exit part to make it simple

Comment: Right... To me, this is just a code smell, and what you have in the original question is better, and I would recommend you go with that, completely your choice though.